# LiveCharts ColumnSeries update Colours on Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am using LiveCharts 0.9.7 and 1.2.9 Geared Version on WPF to show population data on ColumnSeries.

Here is my scenario: At the beginning, I am filling Columns with Blue. I want to change the colour of a single Column's Value on runtime.

I tried to reach a single value with `SeriesCollection[0].Values[0]` but, there no Fill or Colour option, it is just `Double`.

I also tried to cast `SeriesCollection[0] to ColumnSeries` but, I couldn't achieve the result. Is it possible to update a single value's colour on runtime?

```
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; } = new SeriesCollection
{
  new ColumnSeries
  {
    Title = "Population of Bodrum",
    Values = new ChartValues<double> { 1500, 2500, 3700, 2000, 1000},
    Fill = Brushes.Blue
  }
};
```

[image: Population ColumnSeries]

Comment: I've found this, maybe it'll be helpful to you :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195346/different-colors-for-each-value-in-a-columnseries

Comment: I have added and updated a simple solution using a `CartesianMapper`.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a configuration by assigning a `CartesianMapper` to `ColumnSeries.Configuration`.

The following example changes the color of the third column of your given chart from blue to red:

```
public class ChartDataModel
{
  public ChartDataModel()
  {
    this.BlueSeries = new ColumnSeries()
    {
      Title = "Population of Bodrum",
      Values = new ChartValues<double> { 1500, 2500, 3700, 2000, 1000 },
      Fill = Brushes.Blue
    };
    this.SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection() { this.BlueSeries };
  }

  private void ChangeThirdChartPointColorToRed()
  {
    CartesianMapper<double> mapper = Mappers.Xy<double>()
      .X((value, index) => index)
      .Y(value => value)
      .Fill((value, index) => index == 2 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue);

    // Dynamically set the third chart point color to red
    this.BlueSeries.Configuration = mapper;
  }

  // The actual chart data source
  public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }

  private ColumnSeries BlueSeries { get; set; }
}
```

You can also use the `CartesianMapper` to change the color of a point according to its *y* value by specifying a corresponding predicate. To draw all values that exceed a value of 2,000 red you could use the following mapper:

```
 CartesianMapper<double> mapper = Mappers.Xy<double>()
   .X((value, index) => index)
   .Y(value => value)
   .Fill((value, index) => value > 2000 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Blue);
```